# Integrate Constant function using Python

Tags: python, integration

I am doing numerical integration with python, it just does not work for Data with constant values, eg no slope. I know that the analytical integral is obvious, but I still want to know why it does not work in python.

Code:

```
# Integral
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

time = np.linspace(0, 10, num=20)
velocity = time/time

y_integral_numerical = integrate.cumtrapz(velocity, time, initial=0)
y_integral_analytical = time
print(y_integral_numerical)
plt.plot(time, velocity, 'ro',label="Velocity")
plt.plot(time, y_integral_numerical, 'g', label="Numerical Integral-Displacement")
#plt.plot(time, y_integral_analytical, 'b-', label="Analytical Integral-Displacement")

#plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you see that big red warning about division by 0 in `time/time`? Next time you want a constant array, use `constant * np.ones(shape)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple: `time` contains 0, so `velocity=time/time` contains `0/0` as first entry, which is `nan` and then `integrate.cumtrapz` can't calculate the integral.

You should have also seen a warning like the following:

```
/usr/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  #! /bin/sh
```

warning you of the `0/0`.